# what is the return type of __aenter__ and __aexit__?

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following class

```
class MyService:
    def __init__(self, my_api: MyAPI) -> None:
        self._my_api = my_api
        self._session_usage_count = 0

    async def __aenter__(self) -> "MyService":
        if not self._session_usage_count:
            await self._my_api.init() # returns None
        self._session_usage_count += 1
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, *exc: Any) -> None:
        self._session_usage_count -= 1
        if not self._session_usage_count:
            await self._my_api.close() # returns None
```

According to the doc both `__aenter__` and `__aexit__` must return an awaitable,
but in my case it's not. Also I read that `__aexit__` returns bool implicitly.
So what should be the return type in my case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: Annotating an `async def` statement with just the return type of awaiting it is fine.

---

An `async def` statement creates a callable that *always* returns an awaitable. Repeating this in the return type is thus not necessary.

```
from typing import Callable, Awaitable

async def greetings() -> str:
    return "Hello World!"

c: Callable[..., Awaitable[str]] = greetings  # mypy: Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

This allows to use the same return type *annotation* for an async protocol as one would use for the corresponding sync protocol – e.g. `__exit__`/`__aexit__` in this case.

The (async) Context Manager Protocol specifically only says that [`__exit__`/`__aexit__` "should return a true value" if "the method wishes to suppress the exception"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__). It is perfectly fine to return another value/type, including `None`, if the exception should not be suppressed.

Comment: does it mean that everything is correct in my version?

Comment: or it should be `Callable[..., Awaitable[MyService]]`?

Comment: not sure what is the return type of `__aexit__` in that case?

Comment: @IvanPetrushenko I've added some details on the ``__exit__``/``__aexit__`` case. Your annotations are fine.

Comment: do you think it's correct to return `bool` from `__aexit__ ` in my case?

Comment: @IvanPetrushenko Your ``__aexit__`` implicitly returns ``None``, so the ``-> None`` annotation is correct. If you sometimes return a boolean then ``-> Optional[bool]`` is correct, and if you always return a boolean then ``-> bool`` is correct.